# Server side disabled input radio not preserving client changed state on postback

Tags: asp.net

This is a strange one that has been bugging me today. Due to the fact that asp:RadioButtons get rendered in a span I decided to use a std input control with runat="server".

```
<input ID="rbDayRate" type="radio" runat="server" disabled="disabled" />
```

Now as you can see by default this control is disabled. It is enabled by jQuery if the user clicks on a checkbox. However once the state of the control gets to the serverside and I come to use it is not the correct value.

I have checked for all code that is modifying it after the postback data has been loaded and there is none. I have even checked the http post data in Fiddler2 and it is correctly being sent back by the browser.

What's even stranger is if I remove the disabled flag the control works fine.

Any ideas what's going on?!?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Richard,

Reason is, you have disabled the control from the server side, even if you enabled it from client using JQuery, SERVER DOES NOT KNOW ABOUT IT. Therefore it keeps the same value as it is not expecting to change the value of a disabled control...

Try to disable it onload from client, should work this way....

Comment: This is the conclusion that I came to and implemented. However I think this is could be classed as a bug in asp.net as if the control was still disabled when the postback is made it wouldn't exist in the posted data. If it is there asp.net when reloading the control should detect this and change the state as required.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding `enableviewstate="true"` property to the control.  That should allow the control to keep its data/values after postback.

Comment: No this will not work. I am not changing the state of the control in an event or requiring the data to be maintained on a subsequent postback. I am changing the state in JavaScript and I only need it on the first post.

However as usual I had to refresh myself from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx to make sure!  :)